# ajax with page method

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview inside an updatepanel and I have a javascript that calls a page method using jquery. I'd like the page method to refresh the gridview based on the parameter it receives from the ajax call.

So far, I have the following:

1) in the javascript, there's a function that calls the page method:

```
function GetNewDate(thedateitem) {

    DateString = (valid json date format that works)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./CallHistory.aspx/ResetDate",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: DateString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    }) 
};
```

2) In the aspx page I have:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyPanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid">
```

3) In the code behind:

```
public partial class Pages_CallHistory : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<ViewCallHistoryModel> TheCallHistory;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            TheDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 13);
            LoadCallHistory(TheDate);
            MyGrid.Datasource = TheCallHistory;
            MyGrid.Databind;
        }
    }

    protected void LoadCallHistory(DateTime TheDate)
    {
        linq query that fills the variable TheCallHistory
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void ResetDate(DateTime TheNewDate)
    {
        var test = new Pages_CallHistory();
        var test2 = test.LoadCallHistory(TheNewDate.Date);
        //test2 loads fine

        test.GridCallHistory.DataSource = test2; 
        //this is not underlined but bugs at runtime
        //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

        test.GridCallHistory.DataBind();
        test.MyPanel.Update(); 
        //this is not underlined but doesn't get executed because
        //because it stops at the line above

        //I'd like to update the content of 
        //the gridview on the page with the updated gridview.
    }
```

What I'd like to do in the page method is 1) call LoadCallHistory with the new date parameter and 2) tell the gridview MyGrid to rebind with the new data that's in TheCallHistory.

I'm struggling with this page method; it's not working and I'm stuck. How is this done?

Comment: Why is it failing? What results are you getting? Have you tried putting breakpoints and stepping through the code in debug mode to make sure 'TheCallHistory' has the data it's supposed to have? Also, are you sure a gridview can bind to a source such as List<your_object_model>?

Comment: There's more to the page than I could post but in a nutshell, yes, everything works on the page load. There is also sorting and paging inside the updatepanel and that works without refresh. So far in the page method I have:   var test = new Pages_CallHistory();
  test.LoadCallHistory(TheNewDate.Date);
  
  I need to bind the MyGrid and get it to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so the solution is to use _doPostBack in javascript:

```
   __doPostBack('MyPanel', DateString);
```

The page method is for sending and receiving data only, not for doing postbacks on updatepanels.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717804/jquery-and-asp-net-web-forms/4718235#4718235). In short, you create a new instance of the grid and capture its output manually.

Comment: The line to bind the gridview to the datasource is not working; I can't figure it out. Where does the binding occur in your solution?

Comment: I have the line "searchControl.Search()". That would be where you perform your binding, something like "myGrid.DataSource = dataSource;myGrid.DataBind();". After you execute those, the contents can be captured with the RenderControl function.

Comment: These are the lines I already have and that are throwing the exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: That indicates that your myGrid object isn't initialized, which sounds kind of weird. When it tries to reference the DataSource property, it can't find an object reference to access.